# Determinant of a square binary matrix c++

Tags: c++, matrix, binary, determinants

What is the faster algorith for solve the determinant of a square binary matrix in C++?

Comment: Are you asking for an implementation in C++ or an algorithm?

Comment: algorithms - http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~csli/graduate/algorithms/book6/chap31.htm

Comment: I don't know why this was marked as an exact duplicate: this question explicitly asks about *binary* matrices, not the general algorithms for arbitrary matrices with real or complex values. For example Hadamard matrices can take only the values -1 or +1, or equivalently, up to a simple transformation, 1 or 0. Can this be exploited to compute the determinant faster?